# 同じHTML要素名の内容:VALUEを、PHP側で捉える方法を教えてください。

Tags: php, html, html5

標題の件、要素を配列に格納して利用する？？という記事をおみかけしますが
PHPが初めてのことで、よく理解できません。どなたかご教示をお願いできませんでしょうか？

今対応しようとしていることは
羅列されるラジオボタンに、前回指定（クッキー）を受けた指定を自動的に行い、画面利用者の操作軽減を
図る、というものです。

このラジオボタンの羅列は、以下のように動的で生成されます。
現在のところ同名（name=dtype）で配置されますが、解決できれば変更しても良いと考えています。
（name部分に"[]"を付けて配列化する記事をおみかけしましたが、理解ができず現況"[]"なしに留めている）

## ===質問===

以下が今対応しようとしていることのコーディングですが、

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["last_dtype"])){
```

の中でどういった記述を行えば、この目的が達成されるのでしょうか？

```
<?php include "php_classes/classes.php";
    // 伝票タイプのラジオボタンリスト生成
    $sql = "SELECT TYPE, COMMENT FROM WFL_DTYPE WHERE DELFLG=0 ORDER BY TYPE";
    try {
        //DBへ接続 【php_classes/classes.phpに接続先は書いてあります】
        $db = new ms0connect();
        $conn = $db->dbconnect();
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"dtype\" class=\"dtype\" value=\"".$row["TYPE"]."\"/>".$row["COMMENT"];
            PRINT "　\n\t\t\t\t\t";
        }

        $conn = null;

        if (isset($_COOKIE["last_dtype"])){
            //*** name="dtype"のラジオボタンを順次（ループ）参照し、当該HTML要素のvalueが    ***//
            //*** 条件文のクッキーと同値である場合　選択した表示を行いたい。     ***//
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log("### SQL Serverデータ取得失敗 ⇒".$sql."###".$e->getMessage(),0);
        exit();
    } 
?>
```

別途、table内の行違いで同じnameのinput type=text要素を参照していかなければならない課題もあるので、当案件の理解を流用して、こちらも達成したいと考えています。

何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

２つほどポイントが有りますので、長文になりますがご容赦くださいませ。

（１)フォームの配列化について
ラジオであれば択一選択なので配列（name=dtype[]）にする必要はないですね。
チェックボックス等の複数選択であれば必要になります。

（２）HTMLの吐き出しのタイミングでデフォルトチェックを入れる
radioやcheckboxにデフォルトでチェックを入れる方法はinputタグの属性に `checked="checked"`を追加すればいけます。つまりinputタグを生成している処理で
合わせて属性の追加が必要です。
Cookieには最終チェックのradioのvalueが代入されていると仮定すると

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $default_check = "";　//空文字
    if (isset($_COOKIE["last_dtype"])){ //Cookieが設定されている
       if ($_COOKIE["last_dtype"] == $row["TYPE"]) { //更に該当のvalueが設定されている場合
          $default_check = "checked=\"checked\""; // デフォルトチェックの属性を追加
       }
    }
    print "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"dtype\" class=\"dtype\" value=\"".$row["TYPE"]."\" ".$default_check." />".$row["COMMENT"];//Cookieが存在するvalueの値だった場合はデフォルトチェック属性が追加、それ以外は空文字が追加
    PRINT "　\n\t\t\t\t\t";
}
```

上記のようにinputを生成するときにデフォルトチェックを入れるため

Comment: keitaro_so様　ご支援をありがとうございました。完璧です、確かにループの外で達成しようとしていたのが不自然でした。